# SystemError: The connection has been disabled

Tags: python, mysql, ironpython

This is a really nebulous error that I can't seem to get a lot of context for so please ask any questions that might help clarify. I'll try to give you as much context as I can.

I'm currently creating a whole bunch of insert statements for mysql using a comma separated list of parantheses delineated values (i.e. `insert into table (a, b, c) values (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`) I'm creating a thousand of these tuples, joining them with a ',' and inserting them in one statement.

the problem is I'm getting the error in the question.

I've even resorted to connecting to the DB every time I have a new insert statement. I can provide the code if you'dl ike, but it's all masked behind a `with` statement.

I see no reason for the connection to the DB to be dropped....

edit: why not. here's the code. inside a for loop:

```
with SQLConnection(DATASOURCES[SCHEDULEDB]) as db:
    db.execute_sql( command + ' ' + ','.join(block) + ';' )
```

couple of def's:

```
def execute_sql(self, query):
    if query.startswith('select'):
        return self.execute_read(query)
    else:
        return self.execute_other(query)

def execute_other(self,query):
    adapter = OdbcCommand(query,self.connection)
    adapter.ExecuteNonQuery()
    return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that some of the values I was trying to insert into the DB are larger than the VarChar size I allocated for it. The exceptions aren't very enlightening. I ended up checking to make sure each value I insert is smaller than the size allocated for it and raising an exception if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting the error you are getting. Perhaps it has to do with creating very long SQL statements? Whatever the case, you should
always use parametrized SQL statements; avoid composing SQL (with arguments) manually:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)'
args = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
cursor.executemany( sql, args )
```

Comment: please see my edit, i'm not sure this is the issue though it may be.

Comment: @Ramy: I'm not familiar with `OdbcCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery`. The framework you are using seems rather different than the "Python Database API Specification v2.0" (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). The source of the error might have something to do with how you are using that framework, but no matter what framework or db driver you are using, you really should be using parametrized SQL and somehow calling `executemany`. Not only is it easier, but it can help prevent SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection